# Making a SBC working like a networking switch, please help

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I've an single board computer, and I always want's that it works like a switch.

I have one Ethernet port, and one USB > Ethernet converter.

What's my idea?

The traffic is going in to the Ethernet port, and the traffic goes out to the second port, so I can monitor the full network usage of my home.

When I'm trying, and I connect to my computer, Windows says Unknown network, my computer does not get a IPv4 adress, he only detects the gateway correct.

Maybe I need a third Ethernet port for accessing SSH?

I've already enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 and test some command in iptables.
I'm using Armbian Xenial.

Comment: I already fixed it.

Comment: ifconfig enx00606e004adc 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enx00606e004adc -j ACCEPT